# Tight bounds for harmonic measure

Tags: analysis, reference-request, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

I recently came across a question concerning harmonic measure [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206882/mean-value-property-for-harmonic-functions-on-regions-other-than-balls-spheres), and was wondering if there is a good reference summarizing different methods of estimating harmonic measure?
Specifically, I would be interested in special cases like a sharp estimate for convex domains or other domain types.

I found the general *Principle of Extension of Domain* [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Extension_of_domain,_principle_of) (also called *Carleman's Principle of Monotoneity*), however the bound presented there is not optimal according to the source: R. Nevanlinna, "Analytic functions".

Comment: This is possibly not much help, but I recently acquired a copy of [this book](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Harmonic_Measure.html?id=MhXkOC2yAqQC) which is entirely about Harmonic Measure, which looks very good indeed. Unfortunately, I have only read the first chapter so far and do not have the book to hand, so can't guarantee that will help with estimating harmonic measure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- I managed to solve my problem using the book and some references. There's a chapter on estimating Harmonic Measure in there.